# Why the right operand in stream insertion overloading have to be reference?

Tags: c++

For C++ insertion overloading, we usually do:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, X& object){
    // operation
    return os;
}
```

My question here is: why it has to take a reference to the variable object of type X?

Comment: It doesn't have to. But think what taking a value means.

Comment: Do we usually do that? Where did the `const` go?

Comment: Actually "we" usually have them be references to *constant* objects. Or not use references at all and pass by value. And one reason for using (constant) references is that we don't really need a full object, a reference is enough. Why copy (or move) when it's not needed?

Answer (score 3):

> My question here is: why it has to take a reference to the variable
>   object of type X?

You don't need to take a reference, it is not mandatory. In any case, take into account that, since you are not going to modify *object*, it would be better written as:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const X& object){
    // operation
    return os;
}
```

The plain alternative is to pass *object* by value, by writing:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, X object){
    // operation
    return os;
}
```

Where is the problem? Your program will continue working, but its performance will suffer. It is not as efficient to pass a pointer to an object (that is what a reference ultimately is), than to copy the whole object. Imagine that **X** has the following implementation, i.e., it is actually the **GpsTrack** class:

```
/** A complete track, composed by GpsPoints. */
class GpsTrack {
public:
    /** Creates a new, empty track. */
    GpsTrack()
        {}

    /** Adds a new point to the track.
     *  @param p The new point.
     */
    void add(const GpsPoint &p)
        { gpsPoints.push_back( p ); }       

    /** @return The point at position i. */
    const GpsPoint &operator[](int i)
        { return gpsPoints[ i ]; }

    /** @return The number of points in the track. */
    int size() const
        { return gpsPoints.size(); }

    /** @return A textual representation of the track. */
    std::string toString() const;

    /** Adds support for the << operator. */
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const GpsTrack& track)
        { os << track.toString(); return os; }
private:
    std::vector<GpsPoint> gpsPoints;
};
```

Let's take a 32bit machine for the sake of the example. Each **GpsPoint** contains a pair of `double`'s, which are stored in 8 bytes each, so 16 bytes in total. If the **GpsTrack** contains 5000 points, then the result is around 78KB. This is stored in the heap transparently by `std::vector`.

Say that, instead of the implementation given above, we have the following implementation for `operator<<()`.

```
    /** Adds support for the << operator. */
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, GpsTrack track)
        { os << track.toString(); return os; }
```

Then, in order to get that *track* working inside `operator<<()`, C++ will copy the object. The `std::vector` *gpsPoints* will be transparently copied in another vector, duplicating its info in the heap (allocating at the beginning and deallocating at the end of the method). However, this info is made of **GpsPoint**'s, which for the worst case (depends on its implementation), it would imply running over all points and calling their copy constructors. It is not only a waste of time, it is also a waste of resources (i.e. memory).

You can pass it as a const reference, which is as performant as a pointer and as safe (no modifications allowed) as pass-by-value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is worth adding, though, that for PODs passing a reference can actually mean a performance hit. Consider, for example, an "enriched `int`" of some sort: `struct X { int x; /* some methods */ };`. I've seen recommendations on passing as much as `std::string`s by value, in situations where it can be guaranteed to be very short.

Comment: @TheVee `std::string` would be a bad example anyway since it is a flyweight object in essentially every implementation of the c++ standard.

Comment: I am pretty sure that no implementation of `std::string` out there "runs over all characters, copying them". Copying memory is faster than most people think.

Comment: minor nitpick: ".. is as performant as a pointer and safe (no modifications allowed) as pass-by-reference or pass-by-pointer." is slightly misleading, because it can be read as pass-by-reference and pass-by-pointer would imply no modifications allowed

Comment: Thansk for the comments, I think I have now addressed them all.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a *`const`* refererence, you can pass by value as well. Both versions work equally well

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const X &object);

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, X object);
```

The reason for a const reference is usually the same as for other functions: for (large) objects, it is more expensive to copy (i.e. pass by value) than just pass a reference.

Another reason: `const&` works even in cases where no copy constructor is available.

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually we pass either by value or by const reference. Here example from the Microsoft VS2017 implementation. It passes string by const reference, by so we avoid copying and still guarantee not to change the object.

```
template<class _Elem,
    class _Traits,
    class _Alloc> inline
    basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& operator<<(
        basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Ostr,
        const basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>& _Str)
    {   // insert a string
    return (_Insert_string(_Ostr, _Str.data(), _Str.size()));
    }
```